# Is there a simpler way to redirect using a route while adding paramters in Kohana?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I find myself doing the following or similar quite often:

```
Request::instance()->redirect(Route::get('route')
    ->uri(array('action' => 'action')));
```

Or:

```
Request::instance()->redirect(Route::get(Route::name(Request::instance()->route))
    ->uri(array('action' => 'action')));
```

I'm wondering if there's any short, easier, simpler way of doing this. I love the Route functionality, but it makes for some long lines of PHP.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in a controller now, then:

```
$this->request->redirect(Route::url('route', array('action' => 'view')));
```

This could be a little more laconic.

Comment: Made a small fixed. Route::url() still needs the route name.

Comment: @Darryl Hein: oops, yes, missed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the route name directly, you could also pick the current request's route:

```
$this->request->redirect(Request::instance()->route->uri(array('action' => 'action')));
```

note: there is a slight difference with the uri and url methods
Request::redirect uses Url::site to create the correct url